# prevent a dialog from closing after rerun the application

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dialog

I am implementing a dialog function and have a question.

I want to prevent my dialog from closing during a certain period of time. For example, if I set it 10 minutes, the dialog should appear again although a user terminates and reruns the application for the 10 minutes. And after 10 minutes, it will be dismissed and the user can finally use the application. How can I set my dialog to not close for a specific period of time?

I have tried the code shown as below

I implemented the timer by storing the start time with sharedPreference and then **start time - current time > 600000 (10min)**

> Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/layout_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/my_information_button">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_search_edit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
            android:id="@+id/btn_go_search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="#2E6DC6"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_15sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/edit_search"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_search"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bio_email_search_box"
            android:hint="@string/biometric_change_email_hint"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_go_search"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Fragment

```
private lateinit var binding : FragmentHelpBinding
private lateinit var viewModel : HelpViewModel
private lateinit var mContext: MainActivity

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    mContext = context as MainActivity
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_help, container, false)

    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(HelpViewModel::class.java)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel

    otpTimeLimit()
}

private fun otpTimeLimit() = runBlocking {

val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    var startTime = currentTime
    var pref: SharedPreferences? = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("otpTrialLimit", MODE_PRIVATE)
    pref?.edit()?.putLong("startTime", startTime)
    pref?.edit()?.commit()
              
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime <600000) {
        // dialog will show up here and should last for 10 min 
        clickDialog()
    }else if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >=600000) {
        // and when 10 minutes passed, it should dismiss              
    }
}


private fun clickDialog() {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
    val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.help_dialog, null)
    var alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext(), R.style.CustomAlertDialog)
        .setView(view)
        .create()
    val titleText : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.title_text_dialog)
    val contentText : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.content_text_dialog)

    binding.btnGoSearch.setOnClickListener {
        titleText.text = getString(R.string.help_notification)
        contentText.text = getString(R.string.notification_content)
        alertDialog.show()
    }
 }
```

Comment: What is the problem here? Is it not working? Are you asking if that's the right way to do it?

Comment: @DanBaruch I edited the post. I want to know how to implement the function that I explained in the writing

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is when the user sees the dialog, you should store the current date/time and if the user closes and opens the app, get the current date/time and compare it with the stored one.

And don't forget to use : `setCancelable(false)` to prevent the user from closing the dialog

Comment: I already stored it with `sharedPreference` in my codes. And setCancelable(false) is not a function that I am explaining. It's a function not to escape the dialog when the background is touched. My question is not to dismiss the dialog when restarting the app if it's less than 10 min.